# Marketing Cloud - Prevent users from entering multiple responses in landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We send emails to our customers requesting them to click on a link which takes them to our landing page in Marketing Cloud.

They fill in their response in the landing page which is stored in a data extension.

All of this works fine.

But we want our customers to not be able to enter their response again when they click on the link again.

If they click on the link again, we want to show a message like "Thanks.Your response has been recorded" instead of the response form.

Can someone let  know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be able to do like that.

My suggestion would be like this:

- Pass the parameters into the cloudpage URL. E.g. pass their subscriber key into the Cloudpage URL.
- Get the parameter from the cloudpage.
- Make a lookup in the data extension to check if they already have the response or not. If not, then show the form. Otherwise, show the thank you message.

References:

- [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/)
- [RequestParameter](https://RequestParameter)
- [LookupRows](https://LookupRows)
- [Statements](https://ampscript.guide/statements/)